# Python не может считать json со страницы

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, urllib

При использовании класса HTTPCollection модуля http.client, во время считывания содержимого сайта, появляется ошибка 301. Сам сайт отлично работает в браузере, при использовании функции urlopen всё работает. Я понимаю, что решение тут очевидно: просто использовать urlopen, но всё же я хотел бы узнать, почему всё так?

Вот код:

```
from http.client import HTTPConnection
privat = HTTPConnection('api.privatbank.ua', 80)
privat.request('GET', '/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5')
result = privat.getresponse()
print(result.read()) # выводит это: b'<html>\r\n<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor="white">\r\n<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
```

Вот рабочий код:

```
import urllib.request, json 
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    print(data) #выводит это: [{'ccy': 'USD', 'base_ccy': 'UAH', 'buy': '26.70000', 'sale': '26.95000'}, {'ccy': 'EUR', 'base_ccy': 'UAH', 'buy': '30.20000', 'sale': '30.70000'}, {'ccy': 'RUR', 'base_ccy': 'UAH', 'buy': '0.38700', 'sale': '0.41200'}, {'ccy': 'BTC', 'base_ccy': 'USD', 'buy': '3551.4864', 'sale': '3925.3270'}]
```

Не могу понять, почему в первом коде ошибка `301(b'<html>\r\n<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor="white">\r\n<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n')`, а во втором всё отлично работает

Comment: какую ошибку выдает, тут просто у всех открыт доступ к вашему компьетеру

Comment: каким образом что?

Comment: да... видно мой юмор под вечер зашкаливает. извини

Comment: так, так. Весь код из коментов - наверх. и я не очень понимаю вашу проблему

Comment: у вас два куска кода: 1 какой-то, и еще что-то. Четко сформулируйте, что вы хотите услышать от сообщества. "Объясните" - вас скорее всего отправят почитать учебник

Comment: немного изменил, добавил комментарии. Так сойдёт?

Comment: да. так намного лучше. https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html здесь написано, что в конструктор следует передавать полную ссылку. в этом и ошибка)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`301 Moved Permanently` обозначает что адрес страницы поменялся и в заголовке ответа `Location` обычно указывается на какой именно.

Давайте это проверим

```
from http.client import HTTPConnection
privat = HTTPConnection('api.privatbank.ua')
privat.request('GET', '/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5')
result = privat.getresponse()
print(result.getheader('Location'))
# https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5
```

Как видно, адрес реально поменялся -- с `http` на `https`. Вот такой вот редирект.

А что же с `urllib`? А вот что -- он сам сделал редирект:

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5") as rs:
    print(rs.url)
    # https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5
```

---

**PS.**

Похоже, для `http.client` нужно будет в ответе проверить значение [status](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPResponse.status) и для 301 вытащить новый адрес и сделать загрузку по нему. Либо сразу использовать `HTTPSConnection`:

```
from http.client import HTTPSConnection
privat = HTTPSConnection('api.privatbank.ua')
privat.request('GET', '/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5')
result = privat.getresponse()
print(result.read())
# b'[{"ccy":"USD","base_ccy":"UAH","buy":"26.70000","sale":"26.95000"},{"ccy":"EUR","bas ...
```

но, имхо, проще использовать `urlopen`.

Comment: думаю, ругается  потому что ему нужно указывать хост/ip ([см в доку](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection)), а протокол делает невалидным аргумент. То, что вы хотите использовать HTTP или HTTPS следует из названия класса HTTPConnection и HTTPSConnection соответственно. Кст, @ice1x дело говорит -- можно сразу HTTPSConnection использовать, тогда должно сработать -- только уберите порт -- для https дефолтным будет 443, но его можно и не указывать в конструкторе

Comment: большое спасибо, это помогло мне во всём разобраться

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `HTTPSConnection` вместо `HTTPConnection`, 443 порт вместо 80, а после `result.read()`